# Configuring Thunderbird to not delete from server, but not store on local

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I want to use Thunderbird but I have some questions with its mail saving settings.

1. Thunderbird is deleting emails from the server, while downloading them to PC. I don't want to delete emails from the server.
2. I also don't want to store any emails on my computer. I have a few email accounts and use Thunderbird just to keep these accounts together. I won't use any offline email feature.

So, how can I configure Thunderbird for the above?

Comment: Please specify what you mean with "keep the accounts together". Do you want to search through all emails in all accounts of them? Or what else do you need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you want to use IMAP instead of POP for email access. IMAP allows you to view mail on the server itself instead of downloading it to your computer. It's slightly slower for most uses, but prevalent broadband has mostly mitigated that concern.

An explanation of IMAP setup on Thunderbird is here: http://www.techiecorner.com/134/how-to-configure-thunderbird-for-imap-email/